# What is the max Endurance multiplier?

Tags: gemcraft-labyrinth

I've been running `Endurance` levels as of late and was wondering how the multiplier is calculated. So far I've reached `x71.57` using Giant only at level 1337. Does anyone know how this is calculated?

Answer (score 1):

On Gemcraft wiki you can find [list of maximum scores](http://gemcraft.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_Fields_in_Gemcraft_Labyrinth) for each level.
Comparing this to levels' base XP i got the following results:
When there are no buildings (you can't get *destroy all monster nests* amulet) max score multiplier is **x40373.79**.
With some nests on a level max multiplier is **x40898,12**